# J2ME contacts from phonebook &sim NOT reading in Nokia E5 and E72

Tags: java-me, nokia, pim

My j2me application have the feature of messaging with contacts in phone and as well as on sim.I tested Application and running well on Nokia N70 M and Nokia C2-02 also. But not fetching contacts from Nokia E5 and and E72. Please let me know possibilities of errors where I am wrong , Giving you code here...

```
public void loadContacts()
{

    System.out.println("into show contacts1");
    try
    { 
    javax.microedition.pim.ContactList addressbook=null;
    javax.microedition.pim.ContactList simaddressbook=null;
    PIM pim = PIM.getInstance();
    System.out.println("into show contacts2");
    String[] allContactLists = PIM.getInstance().listPIMLists(PIM.CONTACT_LIST);
    System.out.println("into show contacts3");
    for(int ctr=0;ctr<allContactLists.length;ctr++)
    {
    pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY,allContactLists[ctr]);
    addressbook=(javax.microedition.pim.ContactList)(pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY));
    Contact contact = null;
        Enumeration items = null;
        items = addressbook.items();
        while (items.hasMoreElements()) {
            contact = (Contact) items.nextElement();
            int telCount = contact.countValues(Contact.TEL);
            int nameCount = contact.countValues(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME);
            if (telCount > 0 && nameCount > 0) {
                String contactName = contact.getString(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME, 0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < telCount; i++) {
                          String phoneNumber = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, i);
                         ContactFetcher contactfetcher=new ContactFetcher();
                          contactfetcher.setFotmattedName(contactName);
                          contactfetcher.settelName(phoneNumber);
                          PersistableManager pm=PersistableManager.getInstance();
                          pm.save(contactfetcher);
            }
            }
        }
    }
    if(!nokiaos)
    {
      simaddressbook=(javax.microedition.pim.ContactList)(PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE,"SIM"));
     Contact contact = null;
     Enumeration simitems=null;
     simitems=simaddressbook.items();
     while (simitems.hasMoreElements()) {
             System.out.println("into show contacts9");
            contact = (Contact) simitems.nextElement();
            int telCount = contact.countValues(Contact.TEL);
            int nameCount = contact.countValues(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME);
            if (telCount > 0 && nameCount > 0) {
                String contactName = contact.getString(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME, 0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < telCount; i++) {
                          String phoneNumber = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, i);
                          ContactFetcher contactfetcher=new ContactFetcher();
                          contactfetcher.setFotmattedName(contactName);

                          contactfetcher.settelName(phoneNumber);
                          PersistableManager pm=PersistableManager.getInstance();
                          pm.save(contactfetcher);
          }
        }
     }

    }


  }

              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

}
```

Here I am detecting whether phone is s60 or s40 if s6o then only reading pim contacts in s60 and also sim contacts in s40. Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: I have similar issues of fetching contacts from SIM in E72, N70, N73 and many other old nokia manufactured, I don't think that it's a code error rather it could be the different way or no way at all to read from old OS structures. Nokia is the possible thing to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved at last, what i missing some king of naming convention on which contacts are stored. Code is below like that :-
Which running on Nokia E5 and E72 as well.

```
  public void loadContacts()
  {

    System.out.println("into show contacts1");
   try
    { 
    javax.microedition.pim.ContactList addressbook=null;
    javax.microedition.pim.ContactList simaddressbook=null;
    PIM pim = PIM.getInstance();
    System.out.println("into show contacts2");
    String[] allContactLists = PIM.getInstance().listPIMLists(PIM.CONTACT_LIST);
    System.out.println("into show contacts3");

    pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY,allContactLists[0]);
    addressbook=(javax.microedition.pim.ContactList)(pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY));
    Contact contact = null;
        Enumeration items = null;
        items = addressbook.items();
        if(addressbook.isSupportedField(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME) && addressbook.isSupportedField(Contact.TEL))
        {
             while (items.hasMoreElements()) {
             System.out.println("into show contacts9");
            contact= (Contact) items.nextElement();
            int telCount = contact.countValues(Contact.TEL);
            int nameCount = contact.countValues(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME);
            if (telCount > 0 && nameCount > 0) {
                String contactName = contact.getString(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME, 0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < telCount; i++) {
                          String phoneNumber = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, i);

                         ContactPerson.addElement(contactName);    
                         Telephone.addElement(phoneNumber);
                         Imagedata.addElement("");

                     }
                }
             }
        }
        else
        {
            while (items.hasMoreElements()) {
            contact = (Contact) items.nextElement();
            String contactName="";
            contactName = contactName+contact.getStringArray(Contact.NAME,
               Contact.ATTR_NONE)[Contact.NAME_FAMILY];

            if(contactName.equals("null"))
            {
                contactName = contact.getStringArray(Contact.NAME,
                        Contact.ATTR_NONE)[Contact.NAME_GIVEN];
            }
            String phoneNumber=contact.getString(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_NONE);
             if (contactName!=null && phoneNumber!=null) 
             {           
                         ContactPerson.addElement(contactName);    
                         Telephone.addElement(phoneNumber);
                         Imagedata.addElement("");

             }
            }
        }


  if(!nokiaos)
    {
      simaddressbook=(javax.microedition.pim.ContactList)(PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE,"SIM"));
     Contact contactsim = null;
     Enumeration simitems=null;
     simitems=simaddressbook.items();
     if(simaddressbook.isSupportedField(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME) && simaddressbook.isSupportedField(Contact.TEL))
     {
         while (simitems.hasMoreElements()) {
             System.out.println("into show contacts9");
            contactsim= (Contact) simitems.nextElement();
            int telCount = contactsim.countValues(Contact.TEL);
            int nameCount = contactsim.countValues(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME);
            if (telCount > 0 && nameCount > 0) {
                String contactName = contactsim.getString(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME, 0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < telCount; i++) {
                          String phoneNumber = contactsim.getString(Contact.TEL, i);
                         ContactPerson.addElement(contactName);    
                         Telephone.addElement(phoneNumber);
                         Imagedata.addElement("simico.png");


                    }
             }
        }
     }
     else
     {
         while (simitems.hasMoreElements()) {
             System.out.println("into show contacts9");
            contactsim= (Contact) simitems.nextElement();
            String contactName = contactsim.getStringArray(Contact.NAME,
               Contact.ATTR_NONE)[Contact.NAME_GIVEN];

            String phoneNumber=contactsim.getString(Contact.TEL, Contact.ATTR_NONE);
             if (contactName != null && phoneNumber!=null) 
             {
                         ContactPerson.addElement(contactName);    
                         Telephone.addElement(phoneNumber);
                         Imagedata.addElement("simico.png");

             }
          }
        }
     }

 }

              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
   try
   {
                        ContactFetcher contactfetcher=new ContactFetcher(); 
                         contactfetcher.setFotmattedName(ContactPerson);
                         contactfetcher.settelName(Telephone);
                         contactfetcher.setImage(Imagedata);
                         PersistableManager pm=PersistableManager.getInstance();
                         pm.save(contactfetcher); 
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {

   }
}
```